# Use AppleScript to play an iTunes Radio station vs. an iTunes Internet Radio station?

Tags: itunes, applescript

Looking for hints or a code snippet that will show me how to use AppleScript to play an iTunes Radio Station (with cover art, add to iTunes wish list, play more like) vs. playing an iTunes Internet Radio Station. I know how to do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Using Apple Script Editor located in your Utility folder you can do that with this command.

Change the station URL to the one you want.

> tell application "iTunes" to open location
>   "radio2.digitalgunfire.com:8000"

Comment: Your snippet opens an *Internet* Radio Station. I'm looking for a way to open an *iTunes* Radio Station. These are different types of radio stations ... Command+9 to see your Internet Radio Stations ... Command+1 (and click on the Radio link to the right of Playlists) to see your iTunes Radio Stations. Subtle. Thanks for your help!

Comment: simple misunderstanding than, my fault.